# Android: how to set a gradle value from a know enum

Tags: android, gradle

I use [Logger](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger) library in my development, and I configure it in my Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;

    Logger.init(BuildConfig.LOGGER_TAG_NAME)
            //.setMethodCount(3)            // default 2
            //.hideThreadInfo()             // default shown
            .setLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE);  // default LogLevel.FULL
```

**LogLevel** is an enum (in Logger library).

But I want automatically to set the log level according my gradle build type; to do something like that:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        debuggable true

        buildConfigField "enum", "LOGGER_LEVEL", LogLevel.FULL
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        buildConfigField "enum", "LOGGER_LEVEL", LogLevel.NONE
    }
}
```

then:

```
Logger.init(BuildConfig.LOGGER_TAG_NAME)
            //.setMethodCount(3)            // default 2
            //.hideThreadInfo()             // default shown
            .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.LOGGER_LEVEL);  // default LogLevel.FULL
```

But it doesn't work:

> Error:(31, 0) No such property: NONE for class: org.gradle.api.logging.LogLevel

It's the same with FULL enum value.

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You must include the package and class name in both, property type and value:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        buildConfigField "com.orhanobut.logger.LogLevel", "LOGGER_LEVEL", "com.orhanobut.logger.LogLevel.FULL"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "com.orhanobut.logger.LogLevel", "LOGGER_LEVEL", "com.orhanobut.logger.LogLevel.NONE"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gero is it possible to do the same with Kotlin's enum class? BuildConfig is in Java, so seems like having problem identifying Kotlin's enum.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, working with Kotlin as well. Great solution.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid having to repeat the package name and to make the lines shorter, you can define some variable, like:

```
def LogLevel = "com.orhanobut.logger.LogLevel"

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        buildConfigField LogLevel, "LOGGER_LEVEL", "${LogLevel}.FULL"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField LogLevel, "LOGGER_LEVEL", "${LogLevel}.NONE"
    }
}
```